# How to read values from nested JSON structure in java?

Tags: json

How to read values from nested `JSON` without using any library like `GSON` or `org.JSON`?

**JSON is :**

```
{data: { "EV_TOT_AMT" : "12" , "EV_CURR" : "INR", "T_BASKET" : [{"ORDER" : "abc", "BASE" : "xyx"},{"ORDER" : "def", "BASE" : "mno"}] } }
```

I want to read specific values as `EV_TOT_AMT` , `EV_CURR` , `ORDER`.

Comment: Why would you reinvent the wheel? By the way, that's not a valid JSON. The `data` property must be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: sorry about that... its a typo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Java doesn't includes a JSON parser inside it's core classes... so if you don't want to use an external library, you'll need to build your own JSON parser.

Of course, you can just search the JSON string for your desired substrings and get the values moving into the string from the next ":" to the next "," (if the first character after the ":" is not an "["). But this isn't a good approach, unless your JSON input string is going to have always the same structure... well... actually that's not a good approach, period.